# How can use image & video on same frame in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Updated below,

Now I used this methods, it was showed flatingactionbutton on all data, how to only show video data and could I click sizebox then it was playing video not click floatactionbutton and how to hidden floatactionbutton when the user click play video?

```
SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: widget.snap['imageType'] == 'image'
                      ? Image.network(
                          widget.snap['postimage'],
                          //widget.snap['postimage'],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                      // : VideoPlayer(_controller),
                      : _controller.value.isInitialized
                          ? AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                            )
                          : Container(),
                ),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white38,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _controller.value.isPlaying
                          ? _controller.pause()
                          : _controller.play();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    _controller.value.isPlaying
                        ? Icons.pause
                        : Icons.play_arrow,
                  ),
                ),
```

How can use image & video on same frame in flutter?

I tried to used this methods, but I got the errors.

code

```
SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: widget.snap['imageType'] == 'image'
                      ? Image.network(
                          widget.snap['postimage'],
                          //widget.snap['postimage'],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                      // : Image.network(widget.snap['profile_image']),
                      : VideoPlayerController.network(widget.snap['postimage']),
                ),
```

[image]

And this is error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, initialize the video player controller and use like below.

```
VideoPlayerController _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.snap['postimage'];

      SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: widget.snap['imageType'] == 'image'
                  ? Image.network(
                      widget.snap['postimage'],
                      //widget.snap['postimage'],
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
                  // : Image.network(widget.snap['profile_image']),
                  : VideoPlayer(_controller)
            ),
```

Comment: do I need to initialize videocontroller? because it's cannot play video. it's show me black screen....

Comment: Kindly test it on a real device.As sometimes emualtor shows black screen while playing video.

Comment: my video save in firestore. link: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/camping-ee9d0.appspot.com/o/videos%2F1632377430133.mp4?alt=media&token=88b1d765-1fbf-490b-a7e0-3689e96454a9

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are getting error because you VideoPlayerController.network is an object and its not a widget i have updated your code you need to initialize
videoplayercontroller
[image]

```
class VideoExample extends StatefulWidget {
const VideoExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<VideoExample> createState() => _VideoExampleState();
}

class _VideoExampleState extends State<VideoExample> {
VideoPlayerController? _controller;
String data = 'video';

@override
void initState() {
//GET SNAP DATA AND CHECK TYPE OF IMAGE OF NOT IMAGE THEN INITIALIZE 
//USING URL

super.initState();

if (data != 'image') {
  _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/campingee9d0.appspot.com'+
   '/o/videos%2F1632377430133.mp4?alt=media&token' +
     '=88b1d765-1fbf-490b-a7e0-3689e96454a9')
..initialize().then((_) {
   // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, 
   //even before the play button has been pressed.
   setState(() {});
  });
 }
}

@override
void dispose() {
 _controller?.dispose();
 super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   body: SizedBox(
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
   width: double.infinity,
   child: _controller?.value.isInitialized == true
    ? AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        child: VideoPlayer(_controller!),
      )
    : Container(),
 ),
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    if (_controller?.value.isInitialized == true) {
      _controller!.value.isPlaying
          ? _controller?.pause()
          : _controller?.play();
    }
  });
 },
 child: Icon(
     _controller!.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: I'd tried to use your methods, but got error code in inner initState

Comment: @Stanley what i have done i can explain if widget.snap['postimage'] is not 'image'  then i suppose its a videourl then i am initializing it and in build if controller is initialized then display video else image
can you specify what error are you getting

Comment: I saw you edited the context, how to use it in SizeBox function?  like this?

```child: _controller?.value.isInitialized == true
                      ? AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                          child: VideoPlayer(_controller!),
                        )
                      : Image.network(
                          widget.snap['postimage'],
                          //widget.snap['postimage'],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),```

Comment: And it's show me `object event`

Comment: @Stanley i have created working eg by using your video url

Comment: Expected to find ']'.  in floatingActionButton... I dont know why the video always show black screen....

Comment: @Stanley try above code i have uploaded screenshot also

Comment: @thx bro. I found my problems, and I updated my context, if I got the image how could not show FloatingActionButton? Because I used current methods, it's show all data....